# Methods to transfer Tables from source database to destination database using SSIS dynamically

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, data-migration

I am relatively new to SSIS and have to come up with a SSIS package for work such that certain tables must be dynamically moved from one SQL server database to another SQL server database. I have the following constraints that need to be met:

1. Source table names and destination table names may differ so direct copying of table does not work with transfer SQL server object task.
2. Only certain columns may be transferred from source table to destination table.
3. This package needs to run every 5 minutes so it has to be relatively fast.
4. The transfer must be dynamic such that if there are new source tables, the package need not be reconfigured with hard coded values.

I have the following ideas for now:

1. Use transfer SQL Server object task but I'm not sure if the above requirements can be met, especially selective transfer of tables and dynamic mapping of columns.
2. Use SQLBulkCopy in a script component to perform migration.

I would appreciate if anyone could give some direction as to how I can go about meeting the requirements and if my existing ideas are possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the convention is.

Comment: Simplified, my idea would be that you have 2 input parameters. That 2 parameters would be tables name. In SQL command just add In `FROM` part of query, parameter one, and two on another side.